# Why can't I map this array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you help me figure out why I am not able to map this array. Here below are the error and the codes I am running:

```
TypeError: posts.map is not a function
```

and here is my codes causing the above error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'bootstrap-4-react';

export default function Post() {
     //posts array to be mapped
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([{ 
        title: "",
        postContent: ""
    }]);

    useEffect(() => {
    //fetches a GET route
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/posts/:id`).then(res => {    
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setPosts(jsonRes));
    })

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        //cant seem to be able to map this array
        {posts.map(post => {  
            <>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.postContent}</p>
            </>
        })}
    </div>
    )}
```

Comment: What do you get back from the fetch request?

Comment: It seems that your `GET` request is returning a singular object which is why it's not being able to `map` through it. Like @VLAZ asked, what's your `fetch` returning?

Comment: The value of posts might not be an array. Validate the response of the fetch

Comment: I got this when I logged it:

body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:4000/posts/:id"
__proto__: Response

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the mapped returned code block within parenthesis `()`
and not in curly brackets `{}` in order to return the html correctly

```
//...


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
        {posts.map(post => (  
          <>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.postContent}</p>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Edit:
Also, I suggest adding an empty dependency array as the second argument for your `useEffect(() => { //your code }, [])`
This will make it so your component doesn't re-render sporadically and end up fetching your data a ridiculous amount of times.

Comment: I actually noticed that as well and was about to mention it, but note that this will not solve his problem as he is getting an error of not being able to map in the first place, due to posts not being an array at some point.

Comment: He might be fetching his data too often because of no dependency array and could be causing network/api blocks.(updated my answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe because the response is not an array. Try to console.log the response. You can also change its type by using `Array.isArray(jsonRes)`. The second problem is you are not returning the individual element inside the map function.

```
{posts.map((post) => (
        <>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.postContent}</p>
        </>
      ))}
```

Your useEffect also don't have any dependencies, this will result in fetching data on every render. So you must use an empty array as the second argument inside useEffect to tell it to execute only once.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    //fetches a GET route
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/posts/:id`).then(res => {    
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setPosts(jsonRes));
    }, [])
```

Comment: @mallxowed I wrapped it in a parenthesis as suggested, but it broke the app with a:

"src/components/Posts/Post/Post.jsx
  Line 25:18:  'post' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 26:17:  'post' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error."